# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dask-cudf (from versions: none)

Tags: python, python-3.x, gpu, dask, rapids

**Describe the bug**

When I am trying to `import dask_cudf` I get the following ERROR:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-afb970ad91bb> in <module>()
      8 from dask_cuda import LocalCUDACluster
      9 import dask_xgboost
---> 10 import dask_cudf
     11 import dask
     12 from xgboost.dask import DaskDMatrix

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dask_cudf'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have dask and RAPIDS installed with pip

- when I search for: pip install dask_cudf
- original site is not exists anymore: https://pypi.org/project/dask-cudf/
- google stored site history: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:8in7y2jQFQIJ:https://pypi.org/project/dask-cudf/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk

I am trying to install it with the following code in the Google Colab Window
`%pip install dask-cudf`

I get the following ERROR

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dask-cudf (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for dask-cudf
```

On the github page of CUDF is archived. How can I install it to google colab now?
https://github.com/rapidsai/dask-cudf

**Solutions I have tried**

- [ARCHIVED] Dask support for distributed GDF object --> Moved to cudf -> So I install it from  https://pypi.org/project/cudf/ `%pip install cudf`
- On the new Github page from where the achieved point to I can only  see conda installation that doesn't works with Google colab - https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf
- [Rapids install](https://pypi.org/project/rapidsai/): `pip install rapidsai` I thought this is an older version that may be not supported now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**RAPIDS does not support pip install** (https://medium.com/rapids-ai/rapids-0-7-release-drops-pip-packages-47fc966e9472) . Unclear on how you installed RAPIDS using `pip`.
The `pip` install page for RAPIDS (https://pypi.org/project/rapidsai/) states that `conda` should be used in place of `pip` to install RAPIDS.

Please use one of the options provided on the RAPIDS getting started page (https://rapids.ai/start.html) to install RAPIDS.

Also, which version of RAPIDS are you using?

Since Google colab does not support python 3.7 or above, the latest version of RAPIDS cannot be installed on Google colab.

Comment: [Rapids install](https://pypi.org/project/rapidsai/): ```pip install rapidsai``` I thought this is an older version that may be not supported now

Answer (score 1):

FYI it should be working now, though experimental: https://rapids.ai/pip.html

At the time of writing this:

```
pip install cudf-cu11 dask-cudf-cu11 --extra-index-url=https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
```

Comment: I get this error to install pip install: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cudf-cu11 (from versions: 0.0.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cudf-cu11